# Change the user account directory name in WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

is there a way to change the directory name WHM assigns to new cPanel accounts? Right now, the directories are named by the first eight letters in the domain name. Could I change that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In WHM panel,Navigate to `Account Functions` on the `left side of the screen` and click on ***Modify an Account***.  Highlight the **domain** and click ***Modify***.

Now you can change the username of the domain which will also change the directory name